# BiqQuery - select values with max function

Tags: sql, max, google-bigquery

I have this kind of table (just for example.. in my case this table has over 60000 records)

[image]

I would like to know how to make a select to get which gender rate a movieId (or songId) with higher rate?

I do query like this:

```
select * from
(
SELECT avg(rating)as rating, movieID,'M' as gender FROM [OF7.TEST] 
where gender = 'M'
group by movieID
) ,
(
SELECT avg(rating)as rating, movieID,'F' as gender FROM [OF7.TEST] 
where gender = 'F'
group by movieID
) 
order by movieId
```

and get this king of result:

[image]

Question is:
Is there a difference in ratings between genders, which
gender rates movies with higher ratings, is this difference significant?

- is there a way to modify the query to get only the max(rate) for certain songId/movieId and gender?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used bigquery before but something like this should work:

```
SELECT  movieID,
        CASE
            WHEN F_rate >= M_rate THEN F_rate
            ELSE M_rate
        END max_rating,
        CASE
            WHEN F_rate > M_rate THEN 'Females Rated it Higher'
            WHEN F_rate < M_rate THEN 'Males Rated it Higher'
            ELSE 'Rated Equal'
        END AS who_rated_it_higher,
        ABS(F_rate - M_rate) --absolute value of difference

FROM
(
    SELECT  movieID,
            AVG(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN rating END) AS F_rate,
            AVG(CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN rating END) AS M_rate
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY MovieID
) AS A
```

If you have any questions or need anything else, just let me know.